# MS Excel IF statement confusion

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet for some calendars that I'm selling. I have a pricing scheme which depends on how many calendars a customer buys. I want to be able to keep track of sales, but I don't want to have to input the price per unit for each sale. I set up an IF statement that seems to work except for the last variable. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Excel example]

As you can see, it works all the way to the last one. After the number reaches 11, the price per unit should drop to 6, but it doesn't! I know it must be a simple fix, but I don't know much about IF statement, so I'm stuck. Please help!

Comment: I'm at work so I can't reply properly, but a simple `VLOOKUP` with `True` for the 4th argument and a properly set up table is better for this.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the first thing about VLOOKUP, but someone did answer my question with a "workable" IF statement, even if it's not the most friendly code. Any advice for tutorials on VLOOKUP?

Comment: Big +1. 1. Sample data - CHECK! 2. Non-working formula - CHECK! 3. Effort made to self-resolve - CHECK! 4. Lucid description of problem and desired resolution - CHECK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use an `IF` statement, try:

```
=IF(G10=1,9,IF(G10<=5,8,IF(AND(G10>5, G10<11),7,IF(G10>=11,6,IF(G10="","")))))
```

The problem with yours is it will never read the `if(G10>=11` part because it has already evaluated `if(G10>5`

If it should have no output when `G10` is blank, use the following variant:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G10),"",IF(G10=1,9,IF(G10<=5,8,IF(AND(G10>5, G10<11),7,IF(G10>=11,6,IF(G10="",""))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Now I guess I should examine your answer and compare it to mine, and actually figure out how IF works!

Comment: As others have pointed out there are other ways of solving this too. I'd also recommend reading/learning VLOOKUPs

Comment: To learn VLOOKUPs you could start by taking @Nanashi 's answer and try to understand how it works.

Comment: @topsig 

Like I said, your version worked, however, it still doesn't work 100%. I want the cell to be blank if there's nothing in the Quantity column. With the formula that you used, it shows 8. How do I change it so that it won't display anything unless there's something in the Quantity column?

Comment: @user3154077: Just use `ISBLANK`. Something like `=IF(ISBLANK(G10),"",IF(G10=1,9,IF(G10<=5,8,IF(AND(G10>5, G10<11),7,IF(G10>=11,6,IF(G10="",""))))))` should work. Edited the answer above to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work perfectly! Wow, you guys are fast! No sooner do I ask a question, than it's answered!

Comment: Now I've got another question! I have the spreadsheet set to automatically calculate the total price based on the unit price and quantity. However, when the "quantity" cell is empty, then the "total price" cell shows #VALUE. How do I make it blank when there's nothing to show? Screenshot here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtlgacf4yvlgz06/Microsoft%20Excel.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Additional questions in a post after it is answered are frowned upon in SO, so I suggest opening a new post for any future questions. However, since we're already here... use `=IFERROR(SUM(G12*H12+I12+J12),"")`. This should output a blank if the first argument results to any type of error.

Answer (score 3):

If you set up your price table similar to my set-up below, you can use a `VLOOKUP` formula to make it more flexible.

[image]

The formula in `H10` is:

```
=VLOOKUP(G10,$B$1:$C$5,2,TRUE)
```

Enter and drag down.

The benefit of this approach is that you can change the lower bound count on the left and you'll get an adjustment without having to update the formula. Try changing the `2` in `Count` to `3` and you'll see the adjustments right away.

An added benefit is you can add some more values to the table for further pricing brackets.

Comment: Another benefit is better formula auditing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Nanashi that putting the price thresholds in a separate table and using vlookup is a better solution. That would make it possible to change the price points without having to edit multiple formulae.

But to just get your formula working, try this: `=if(g10="","",if(g10=1,9,if(g1<=6,8,if(g10<=10,7,6))))`

Notice that:

- You don't need (and probably don't want) quotes around your numeric
  values
- The order of tests is important. In your original, the test for `g10>=11` is never reached because it is in the `else` part of the `g10>5` function.

Comment: Just adding to the discussion, VLOOKUP to a table, will make auditing the formulas easier (i.e. easier to insure all formulas are the same), and avoids the use of hard-coded or "magic" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A properly constructed table of quantities and pricing coupled with a `VLOOKUP` formula would be the best way to go and eases future pricing changes. But for the sake of diversity, your straightforward pricing structure could also be handled by the following:

`=(6+(G10<11)+(G10<6)+(G10<2))*(G10>0)`

Answer (score 0):

In the formula, "G10>5" should be "G10<=10".  Otherwise, when it gets to 11, it still meets the G10>5 criteria.

Comment: (I agree though with @Nanashi... I would have done a VLOOKUP instead).